# Sharepoint Workflow Logic

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, infopath

Hello there I have a infopath form with Sharepoint workflow attached to it. I want to be able to send an email to a certain person based on what the "users" last name starts with.

So for example:

Person 1 last name starts with A,B,Y that email is sent to cindy@home.com
Person 2 last name starts with M through Z email is sent to joe@home.com

I know that I can do "If CurrentItem:LastName begins with value" but I do not know how to set up the value part.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to set up a compound condition like this:

```
If CurrentItem:LastName begins with 'A' or CurrentItem:LastName begins with 'B' or CurrentItem:LastName begins with 'Y' then
```

See [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2008/05/14/create-compact-and-powerful-conditions-in-your-workflows.aspx) for an example of how to set that up. Here are some samples from that article:
[image: Example]
This can also be reduced to:
[image]

You can also do this as a regular expression for finding one that starts with M-Z. Use the regex variable: `^([M-Z]|[m-z])` which means match any string that starts with any letter m-z upper or lower case.
[image]

Comment: Ok Great I think that works. But now What about if I want to do a range IE M-Z

Comment: That is where you will want to use regular expressions. See the bottom for the article for an example

Comment: I updated the answer with a regex example. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem using the check button.

Comment: Sorry I guess I do not understand. Where do I add the regEx in the WF?

Comment: Store your regex in a new variable then use the "matches regular expression" operator

Comment: Sorry Am i doing this from code or without code? :)

Comment: Never mind I think I may  have figured it out. I will keep you posted.